# Are there any tutorials or guides for setting up an Apple Push Notification server in Rails (3.0)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, ruby-on-rails-3, apple-push-notifications, mongoid

I've got an app that I am building in Rails 3 (and MongoDB using Mongoid). I want to be able to send Apple Push Notifications to iOS devices. I am aware of PRX's apn_on_rails and samsoffes' apple_push_notification gems, but they do not appear to work correctly in Rails 3.

Are there any tutorials out there for setting up an APN server in Rails 3 (and Mongo)?

Comment: If you are not sure if PRX's apn_on_rails is running with rails 3 and mongo, you should try, and ask for help if you have problems to get it running. we are no guinea pigs to try something you won't bother to try yourself first

Comment: I didn't mean to get people to be guinea pigs. I tested PRX's apn_on_rails as well as samsoffes' apple_push_notification gems and they both don't appear to be working correctly in Rails 3.

Comment: When they do not appear to be working, then you should open a bug ticket for them, or try to fix the bug. Or you can try again and describe to us what exactly went wrong, and maybe we can figure out to get these gems get working with rails3

Comment: I ended up attempting to fix the gem myself, and it "worked", but none of the gems support Apple's feedback system, as well as batching notifications. I was just curious to see if anyone has actually implemented an APN server in Rails. In this sense, I think fixing these gems wouldn't be sufficient.

I'm not asking people to do it for me, I just wanted to know if someone has done this before and could offer some insight.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for Rails 3? Or you just used the one you fixed?

Answer (score 0):

The [Apn On Rails project](https://github.com/PRX/apn_on_rails) is closely dependent of ActiveRecord and ActiveRecord is not compatible to MongoDB. So you can't use it with MongoDB.

Your solution is to fork this project and use Mongo like database instead of ActiveRecord or open some issue to become apn_on_rails ORM agnostic.